# cannot change data type of view column from numeric to numeric(4,1)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to calculate a ratio with 1 decimal place. So I created a view using

```
create or replace view MyView
as
select cast(A/B as numeric(4, 1)) as ratio from MyTable;
```

A is int type and B is real number with 3 decimal places
and I'm getting an error

> cannot change data type of view column "ratio" from numeric to numeric(4,1)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you cant change the column datatype in view. drop and recreate instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drop` first:

```
drop view MyView;
create or replace view MyView as
select cast(A/B as numeric(4, 1)) as ratio 
from MyTable;
```